# Creating a Minecraft-esc Game. Problems with Chunks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, minecraft, truncate

I am creating a Minecarft like game in Unity, using c#. Everything good so far. Chunks Spawn / Despawn, but they build up like they were spawned, without the Players input (broken blocks) being recognized. Long story short:

I have a value, lets say 401.00 or 304.00 and need to make them into 1 or 4, so that only the first number infront of the decimal point is chosen. How do I do that? I have found absolutely nothing, but maybe I searched wrong?

Comment: Modulo(%) 10 and convert to int?

Answer (score 1):

```
int myInt = 401

while (myInt >= 10)
    myInt = myInt % 10
```

This should work for any number.